# Why BIP32 derive address does not match with BIP39?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, bip

How is that the same xPub rsults different address in BIP32 and BIP39? :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't. You read it wrong, first snippet shows you account key for `m/44'/0'/0'/0` derivation path, second snippet for `m/44`. As the derivation paths are different - obviously the accounts' keys are different too.